# How to save HDR file with numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imageio, hdr, imghdr

I try to save HDR file with numpy array as follows.

numpy array like this (dtype:np.float32)

```
# hdr_file_data
[[[0.32543945, 0.38671875, 0.44213867],
  [0.30029297, 0.34204102, 0.3737793 ],
  [0.2697754,  0.28515625, 0.28295898],
  [0.2388916,  0.23449707, 0.20837402]],

 [[0.35668945, 0.4309082,  0.49853516],
  [0.32495117, 0.37939453, 0.4230957 ],
  [0.2836914,  0.3059082,  0.3088379 ],
  [0.2454834,  0.24353027, 0.21777344]],

 [[0.46069336, 0.54248047, 0.6040039 ],
  [0.4128418,  0.47705078, 0.51708984],
  [0.33666992, 0.3684082,  0.3713379 ],
  [0.28027344, 0.2854004,  0.26000977]],

 [[0.64697266, 0.7270508,  0.7607422 ],
  [0.60302734, 0.6665039,  0.67871094],
  [0.49047852, 0.52783203, 0.515625  ],
  [0.38598633, 0.40063477, 0.37036133]]]
```

I use imageio lib to save HDR file like:

```
imageio.imwrite(filenameA,hdr_data, format='HDR-FI')
```

And then i try to use

```
imageio.imread(filenameA,format='HDR-FI')
```

to check the value is correct. However, the pixel values as follows are different with above hdr_data. How can I make sure the values are correct?

```
[[[0.32421875, 0.38671875, 0.44140625],
  [0.29882812, 0.34179688, 0.37304688],
  [0.26953125, 0.28515625, 0.28125   ],
  [0.23828125, 0.234375,   0.20800781]],

 [[0.35546875, 0.4296875,  0.49804688],
  [0.32421875, 0.37890625, 0.421875  ],
  [0.28320312, 0.3046875,  0.30859375],
  [0.24511719, 0.24316406, 0.21777344]],

 [[0.45703125, 0.5390625,  0.6015625 ],
  [0.41015625, 0.4765625,  0.515625  ],
  [0.3359375,  0.3671875,  0.37109375],
  [0.27929688, 0.28515625, 0.25976562]],

 [[0.64453125, 0.7265625,  0.7578125 ],
  [0.6015625,  0.6640625,  0.67578125],
  [0.48828125, 0.52734375, 0.515625  ],
  [0.38476562, 0.40039062, 0.36914062]]]
```

Comment: and how does this "HDR-FI" format store the data? as floats? as integers? quantized in what way? the output looks like 10 bit quantization, while the input appears to be at least 13 bits quantized.

Comment: I don't know how HDR-FI is stored